# Java thread still in memory after being shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading

Could some help me fix this. The code below is what I am using to start/stop some Polling service. The Polling service operates with a `while(boolean running)` loop. Calling `Polling.setRunning(false)` would terminate the loop.

```
private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
   @Override
   public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
      Thread thread = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(runnable);
      thread.setDaemon(true);
      return thread;
   }
});

public static void start(){

    pool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                System.out.println("Starting Polling...");
                Polling.start();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}

public static void stop(){

    System.out.println("Stopping Polling...");
    Polling.setRunning(false);
    pool.shutDownNow();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    start();    //call to start

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    stop();     //call to stop

}
```

Question is: when I run this everything works fine and as expected. However, when I run:
`ps -ef | grep java` it shows that the program is still running in background. Even though the polling service has definitely stopped!

Why does this happen? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Without the code to your Polling class it's difficult to give feedback, but it's likely you have a thread which is not detecting that Polling is no longer in a running state.

Comment: @Larry: you didn't paste enough.  Then what do you mean by *while(boolean running)*?  That's no Java syntax.  Then is *running* volatile?  Then what happens if you add some logging like a *System.out.println* once you exit your *while* loop?  Does it print something?

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: No, it won’t print anything. In polling I have a while(running) loop where running is of type boolean defined as global static. Calling .setRunning(boolean) allows to change the value of running.

Comment: @Larry: if your global static is not declared *volatile* and if you're not writing and reading to it from *synchronized* blocks than there are exactly **ZERO** guarantee that a write to your *running* boolean shall be seen by other threads.  That's just for a start, I suspect there's something else at work here :(

Comment: @SyntaxT3rr0r: what you’re saying is really similar to what I have been reading, but I’m not sure I understand. Could you write up some sample code to show how I should organise the running boolean, so that it can be seen by children threads.

Comment: @Larry: All I'm saying is that for a start you should add the "volatile" keyword to your *running* boolean.  So if you have *private static boolean running* simply change it to *private static volatile boolean running*.  But once again, that is just *one* change.  You may consider not using a *"cancellation request flag"* (that's the name of your boolean) but using the Java interruption facilities instead.  And then the problem may be something else entirely.  It's hard to tell for you didn't paste the complete code so we cannot reproduce the issue :-/

Comment: @Larry: also, technically *running* is a very poor name.  Your cancellation request flag should be called something like *"cancelled"* and your while loop should be *while (!cancelled)* (that's how the cancellation request flag is implemented in the *Java Concurrency In Practice* book).

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a thread dump to see which non-daemon threads are still running.

`jstack`, `visualvm` or `jconsole` are a few ways to do this.

You can force the application to stop with

```
System.exit(0);
```

As polling is in a daemon thread it won't matter if its stopped or not. The program would finish regardless.

Comment: @Jeff Storey, agreed. possibly friendlier as well.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you **should not** roll your own `boolean` flag. Instead, use the thread's own *interrupted status*.

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    // do stuff
}
```

If you read the javadoc concerning [`shutdownNow()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29), it says

> ... any task that fails to respond to interrupts *may never terminate*

I believe this **would not** be the case if you implemented the above logic. Also, if you perform any blocking operations, you'll need to *propagate the interruption* to ensure that the thread receives the interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

In your processing, are you catching Exceptions and continuing processing? Are you not allowing the ThreadInterruptException to trickle up and cause the Thread to shut down?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing that the Java process is alive, it is because there is atleast one daemon thread in the JVM. The API documentation of the [`Thread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class states:

> The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of
>   the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security
>     manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by
>     returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception
>     that propagates beyond the run method.

And therefore, this line of code in your `ThreadFactory` implementation ought to explain why the process continues to be alive:

```
thread.setDaemon(true);
```

All `Runnable` tasks that are submitted to the `ExecutorService` will now be run as daemon threads. You ought to verify whether the threads that have been initialized have been terminated or not. This also includes the thread that is executes your polling loop (and need not be the main thread, depending on how you've written the `Polling` class).

If you've reviewed your code and you haven't figure out what section is responsible for the daemon thread to be alive, you adopt one of the following techniques to determine what thread is preventing the JVM from shutting down:

- Send a `SIGQUIT` signal to the Java process. This will give you a thread dump of the JVM, with the stacks of all the threads; you will need to redirect stdout to a file, in case your JVM process is running as a background process. In the resulting stack trace, you should find at least one daemon thread that is alive and executing a section of code in your application.
- Consider setting a [`name`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29) to the threads initiated by the `ThreadFactory`. This way, should you use a logger that prints out the thread name along with a message at the end of the `run` method, you can determine whether  threads are alive by noting the absence of any messages.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any blocking queue or any resource? Because how normally it works is that, when you call up shutDownNow(), it throws an interrupt to the thread, if the pool thread hasnt started executing the Runnable, it terminates, if not then it has to wait till the end.
Now the point is if you are using a BlockingQueue or Asynchronous I/O with Selector or whatever, each has its own policy of how it deals with interrupts. Say if you used a BlockingQueue, and say it was is waiting for a Runnable, and at the same moment an interrupt is received, then it throws an InterruptedException and the interrupt status is cleared.
ie you will have manually let the stack know, that an interrupt was thrown by:

```
try{
runnable.run();
}
catch(InterruptedException ex)
{
Thread.currentThread.interrupt();//let the stack know that interrupt was thrown.
}
```

If your case is the above case, without the catch statement, the thread will never terminate, because the interrupt status is cleared as soon as the Exception was thrown.
Hence depending on the package you use, check the interruption policy.
It will be better if you can provide the code in Polling